# [[ and case equivalency in bash

Tags: bash, wildcards, test

Does

```
if [[ "$1" = pattern ]]; then
    hook
fi
```

always behave the same as

```
case "$1" in
    pattern) hook;;
esac
```

or are there any gotchas?

Comment: I can't find any cases where they differ, regardless of `shopt` settings and values in `$1` or `pattern`, nor in `$?` afterwards. The only difference is that `$1` is not expanded in the output when running under `xtrace`.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, they are (almost) completelly equivalent.

---

## Detail

Inside a `[ … ]` construct:

The `=` operator (or even the non-posix option of `==` ) tests string matching, not pattern matching.

Inside a `[[ ]]` construct (from man bash):

> When  the  ==  and  !=  operators are used, the string to the right of the operator is considered a pattern and matched according to the **rules** described below **under Pattern Matching**.  If the shell **option nocasematch** is enabled, the match is **performed without  regard  to  the  case**  of alphabetic characters.  The return value is 0 if the string matches (==) or does not match (!=) the pattern, and 1 otherwise.  Any part of the pattern may be quoted to force it to be matched as a string.

Inside a `case` construct (from man bash, edited and emphasis mine):

> case word in [ [(] pattern [ | pattern ] ... ) list ;; ] ... esac
>   ... tries to match it against each pattern in turn, using the same matching **rules** as for **pathname expansion** (see Pathname Expansion below). …   Each pattern examined is expanded using tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, arithmetic substitution, command substitution, and process substitution.  If the shell **option nocasematch** is enabled, the match is performed **without regard to the case** of alphabetic characters.

Both `Pattern Matching` and `Pathname Expansion` are used to mean the same inside the bash manual.

The only difference I can see in the manual is:

```
`[[ … ]]`                                   case
tilde  expansion                            tilde expansion
parameter and variable expansion            parameter and variable expansion
arithmetic expansion                        arithmetic substitution
command substitution                        command substitution
process substitution                        process substitution
quote removal
```

That `quote removal` is not explicitly listed for the case construct.
Which works to exactly match this (for the `[[ … ]]`):

> Any part of the pattern may be quoted to force it to be matched as a string.

Use this to test this last point (now the variable is **not** a pattern):

```
case "$1" in
  "$pattern") echo case match
esac
```

---

## Why almost?

1. Implicit `extglob`:

   Since [version 4.3 of bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html)

   > When the ‘==’ and ‘!=’ operators are used, the string to the right of the operator is considered a pattern and matched according to the rules described below in Pattern Matching, **as if the extglob shell option were enabled**.

   That means that a pattern used with the option `extglob` **unset** will work differently in a case statement and inside a `[[` construct after bash version 4.3.
2. Implicit `|`:

   The syntax for case is:

   ```
   case word in [ [(] pattern [ | pattern ] ... ) list ;; ] ... esac
   ```

   Which means that there may be several patterns separated by a `|` (OR).

   Like this:

   ```
   shopt -s extglob;      p1="+([0-9])";       p2="+([abcde])"

   case "$1" in
       $p1|$p2)    echo "or case match" ; ;;
   esac
   ```

   Which will match either a string of only numbers or only letters in `abcde`, like `1234` or `aabee`, but not `12a` or `b23`.

   A `[[` will work equivalently if **regex** (look at var p3) are used:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   shopt -s extglob           ### Use extended globbing.
   shopt -s globasciiranges   ### The range [a-z] will expand to [abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz].

   pattern="+([0-9])"
   p1="+([0-9])"
   p2="+([a-z])"
   p3="^([0-9]+|[a-z]+)$"

   case "$1" in
       $pattern)   echo case1 match ; ;&
       $p1|$p2)    echo case2 match ; ;;
   esac

   [[ "$1" == $pattern ]] && echo if1 match
   [[ "$1" =~ $p3 ]] && echo if2 match
   ```